# Subtensor of a Tensorflow tensor (C++)

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a `tensorflow::Tensor batch` in C++ with shape [2, 720, 1280, 3] (#images x height x width x #channels).

**I want to get another tensor with only the first image**, thus I would have a tensor of shape [1, 720, 1280, 3]. In order words, I want:

`tensorflow::Tensor first = batch[0]`

What's the most efficient way to achieve it?

I know how to do this in python, but the C++ api and documentation are not as good as python's.

Comment: Maybe you could show some snippet for context? You have a `tensorflow::Tensor`, right? And you want to produce another `tensorflow::Tensor` with that image, or extract that data into something else?

Comment: Exactly. I have a tensorflow::Tensor and I want a "subtensor" with only the first image. In other words, what I want is basically originalTensor[0, :, :, :]. I will edit my question with your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. So the shape you expect in the result is `[1, 720, 1280, 3]` or `[720, 1280, 3]`? I know the number of elements is the same, but the construction of the tensor is slightly different. In Python, you would get the first one with `batch[:1]` and the second one with `batch[0]`.

Comment: I prefer the result with shape [1, 720, 1280, 3], but [720, 1280, 3] may be not a problem after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time trying to implement through copy, I realised that this operation is supported in the API as [`Slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#slice):

```
tensorflow::Tensor first = batch.Slice(0, 1);
```

Note that, as documented, the returned tensor shares the internal buffer with the sliced one, and the alignment of both tensors may be different, if that is relevant to you.

---

*EDIT:*

Since I had already done it, here is my attempt at reproducing the same functionality, copy-based. I *think* it should work (it is pretty similar to what I use in other context).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.h>

tensorflow::Tensor get_element(const tensorflow::Tensor data, unsigned int index, bool keepDim)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace tensorflow;

    typedef typename tensorflow::DataTypeToEnum<T> DataType;
    auto dtype = DataType::v();
    assert(dtype == data.dtype());

    auto dtype = data.dtype();
    auto dataShape = data.shape();

    TensorShape elementShape;
    if (keepDim)
    {
        elementShape.addDim(1);
    }
    for (int iDim = 1; iDim < dataShape.dims(); iDim++) {
      elementShape.AddDim(dataShape.dim_size(iDim));
    }
    Tensor element(dtype, elementShape);
    auto elementBytes = elementShape.num_elements() * DataTypeSize(dtype);

    memcpy(element.flat<void>().data(),
           batch.flat<void>().data() + elementBytes * index,
           elementBytes);
    return element;
}

int main()
{
    Tensor batch =  ...;
    Tensor first = get_element(batch, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The code can also be changed if you just want to extract the data to, for example, a vector or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked, but I now have the problem with aligment using the function flat() later in the code, as reported by the documentation. Again, the documentation is not so clear about it. Do you know what "alignment" means?

Comment: @ArnaldoGualberto Truth be told, there is little documentation on what that exactly means and what are the implications of that warning. My understanding (and I may be wrong) is that if [`IsAligned()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#isaligned) return false then calling [`flat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#flat) and similar will not work as expected. In that case, maybe you can [copy-construct](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#tensor_7) another tensor and operate with that?

Comment: Actually, it might make sense to create an issue requesting a better clarification of this, and/or some example.

Comment: @ArnaldoGualberto I have added my copy-based attempt, in case you find that useful...

Comment: Let's say I had images grouped in tracks so the dims would be `[4, 2, 720, 1280, 3]`. And I wanted the first image of the first track.  Is there a way to do this via the C++ API? Looks like slice only works along the first dimension.

Comment: @KeithJohnson I think you should be able to do that using the [`chip`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title87) operation: `myTensor.chip(0, 0).chip(0, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_slice.h"

Tensor t2 = t1.Slice(0,1);
```